# Unable to see data from RedDot LiveServer page?

Tags: content-management-system, reddot

I have created a reddot cms component, in which I added this line

Also, I created a dynament in livesever having name as SomeFileName.xml .The job it is doing is to fetch a table colum from a database. The query works well in SQL Server and also when I define the connector.

But I am unable to get any data if I open the CMS page in any browser. To me, it seems that I am missing some configuration. I am using v 9.0 of both CMS and LiveServer. I am also using SQL Server 2005 as my database.

Please tell me if I am missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try accessing the page directly through tomcat, aka, http://hostname-of-liveserver:8080/cps/rde//path/to/SomeFileName.xml

This should contain the raw XML output of your operations. If you're not getting enough information, try attaching a report tag to your query dynament to get a little more:

```
report-tag="some-report-tag"
```

If a blank page comes up or appears to be having errors, try checking your rde.log for any errors. If it's too large, rename it and then re-run the request.

If you ask me, it sounds like it's either a syntax issue with the file or a problem with your XSL rendering HTML.